# Referencing jQuery element between fileupload plugin methods

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I need to be able to reference a created jQuery Element in both the add method and done method of the jQuery file upload plugin. It is created in the add method but needs to be replaced in the done method

Currently during multiple uploads the theFilemanagerRow is overwritten each time by the next iteration of the next file

Question is: how do I access the unique theFilemanagerRow from the "add" function in the "done" function for each unqiue file uploaded when multiple files are uploaded.

Single files work however it seems that for multiple file selections the add function is run for each of the multiple files so it overwrites the theFilemanagerRow and the done function only receives the theFilemanagerRow that is set by the "add" function at the time that "done" completes - hope that makes sense!!

```
frameContainer.find('INPUT[type=file]').each(function() {
  var file_field = $( this );
  var theFilemanagerRow = false;

  file_field.fileupload({
    dataType:     'json',
    formData:     formData,
    add:          function(e, data) {
                    //need reference to element here
                    theFilemanagerRow = $('<tr>', {
                      id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10)
                    });
    },
    done:         function(e, data) {
                   if (theFilemanagerRow.length == 1) {
                     theFilemanagerRow.replaceWith(anotherElement);
                   }
    }
  });

});
```

I have simplied the code for clarity here so the elements are used in the document, anotherElement is created elsewhere, etc.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `id` of element in `document` should be unique. You would be creating multiple elements having same `id` `656564654878`. Also, you do not appear to be actually appending the element to `document`?

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity - rest assured that I am using elements created but have simplified the code for easier reading

Comment: @TimWiel You can use `.data()` to store jQuery object at the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `data.context`

```
  add: function(e, data) {
    // need reference to element here
    var theFilemanagerRow = $("<tr>", {
      id: /* set id */
    });

    data.context = theFilemanagerRow;
  },
  done: function(e, data) {
    // get `.data()` of current element
    var tr = data.context;
    if (tr.length == 1) {
      tr.replaceWith(anotherElement);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think I have narrowed it down to the `file_field.fileupload({` runs the add function for each multiple file and then runs the done function for each multiple file but the two don't always run in orderas and as my code currently stands the add function sets the variable but the equivalent done doesn't always get the variable it corresponds too.

Comment: @TimWiel Are you trying to create the element only once for multiple uploads, or once for each upload? Are you indicating that `add` is occasionally called before `done`?

Comment: I am trying to create the element for each file of the multiple upload.

Comment: Its seems that https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options is the documentation for this functionaility but I can't seem to find where or if you can get scope for variables between callback functions

Comment: This could probably accomplished using `javascript` or jQuery alone. Is using `fileupload` plugin part of requirement?

Comment: Unfortunately the `fileupload` plugin is required - I think the core of the issue is weather callbacks can reference each other within the fileupload object

Comment: @TimWiel Is the `.data()` of the element not defined between `add` and `done` callbacks? Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net including the `html`, `javascript` which you have tried?

Comment: @TimWiel Believe determined what is occurring.  `done` fires for each upload when multiple files are selected. Are you trying to call a function at `done` when all uploaded have completed? Or at each file upload at `done`?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/ChJ9B/ ?